# Which US treasury security is the most important

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

I have recently realized that the US treasury security has a big impact on the market.

So, which security should I follow?

Is the U.S. 10 Year Treasury Note rate the most important?

Also, which interest rate should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

2 year and 10 year are most important for the yield curve, roughly representing the short and long ends of the curve. The [shape of the curve](https://www.fidelity.com/learning-center/investment-products/fixed-income-bonds/yield-curve-and-yield-curve-dynamics) tells you something, as do the real and nominal rates of the 2 year and 10. (Real rates are rates adjusted for inflation).

The shortest end of the curve is the end that is most controllable by the Fed, so the 1 month T-bill is also important to see what the Fed is directly controlling.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other interest rate I should pay attention to? Like Fed interbank interest rate?

Comment: Sure, that is the one actually set by the Fed. Could ignore the 1-month bill and follow the Fed Funds Rate.